# Configure SFML On CLion For VS Compiler

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, clion, vcpkg

I downloaded SFML using vcpkg, and I wanted to use SFML in CLion. So, in the CMake options I put:

```
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake
```

for using vcpkg modules.

My CMakeList.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(Test)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

FIND_PACKAGE(SFML REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(Test main.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Test ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENC})
```

CMake shows:

```
  Found SFML 2.5.1 in C:/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/share/sfml
```

But CLion tells me that SFML/Audio.hpp was not found.

Is there something wrong with my CMakeList?
How can I configure SFML in CLion?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Potentially unrelated, but `${SFML_DEPENDENC}` doesn't look valid...

Comment: Thank you but it's still don't work